# Select rows from two tables to json array

Tags: php, sql, json, mysqli, row

I am a beginner  developer and it is very difficult for me to understand as it to make.
Please help me.

**catbook**

```
+----+---------+------------+
| id | cat_num | count_book |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 |   55555 |         21 |
|  2 |   77777 |         40 |
+----+---------+------------+
```

**userbook**

```
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+
| id | user_name | cat_userbook | read_count |
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+
|  1 | Andy      |        55555 |          3 |
|  2 | Andy      |        77777 |          5 |
|  3 | Tom       |        55555 |          4 |
|  4 | Tom       |        77777 |          8 |
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

**Code**

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

$user_name = "Andy";

$sql ="SELECT cat_userbook, read_count, count_book FROM userbook, catbook WHERE user_name LIKE '" . $user_name . "'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
$response = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $response[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($response);
mysqli_close($db_connect);
```

**result:**

```
[
 {"cat_userbook":"55555","read_count":"3","count_book":"21"},
 {"cat_userbook":"55555","read_count":"3","count_book":"40"},
 {"cat_userbook":"77777","read_count":"5","count_book":"21"},
 {"cat_userbook":"77777","read_count":"5","count_book":"40"}
]
```

but I want this result as it is necessary for me so:

```
[
 {"cat_userbook":"55555","read_count":"3","count_book":"21"},
 {"cat_userbook":"77777","read_count":"5","count_book":"40"}
]
```

Comment: You need to tell DB server to return only lines where `cat_num = cat_userbook`. Learn something about [JOINS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Answer (score 1):

If you are joining like this: userbook, catbook
u get userbook x catbook

I think what you are looking for is:

```
SELECT cat_userbook, read_count, count_book FROM userbook LEFT JOIN catbook ON catbook.catNum = userbook.cat_userbook WHERE user_name LIKE '" . $user_name . "'";
```

Comment: You so quickly repelled. This is a working solution for me. Thank you very much

Comment: where is the to json array from 2 joining table?